# use Html in java SpringBoot V2.4.1 Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/signup" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String PostSignUpPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute Users users , BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes attributes){
      
       if(usersRepositor.findByEmail(users.getEmail()) != null){
attributes.addFlashAttribute("user_exiting" ,"You are already registered ");
attributes.addFlashAttribute("user_exiting_class" , "alert alert-warning");
            return "redirect:/signup";

        }
```

And in Html code I use this code

```
<div th:if="${user_exiting !=''}" th:text="${user_exiting}" th:class="${user_exiting_class}"></div>
```

I need use after "You are signup " message a Hyperlink like this

```
<a href="#"> Login</a>
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to do? What is your final goal?

Comment: I need add login Link after REGISTERED word 
https://files.fm/u/2axgnzkts#/view/cz6x9y2fb

Answer (score 0):

you can do after signup i.e after submitting it is better redirect to login page directly

@RequestMapping("/sigup")

public String signup(){

return "redirect:/login"

}